# Specific Characters in Palindrome Program Do not work

Tags: string, palindrome, strcmp

Here is my code. The list of characters that do not "work" and continue to say that they are palindromes if wrapped around the cin still say they are correct. The list of characters that don't work are:

single quotes, double quotes, commas, periods, forward slashes, back slashes, dashes, exclamation points, @ symbols, # symbols, $ symbols, % symbols, ^ symbols, & symbols, * symbols (asterisk), equals symbols, + symbol

```
int main()
{
int k = 1;
int i;
int length, halflength;
int yesno = 1;
char string [81];
char end[81] = "END";
while (k = 1)
{
    cout << "Please enter a string of characters. " << endl;
    cout << "Enter \"END\" in all caps to exit the program." << endl;
    cin.getline(string, 81);
    if (strcmp(string, "END") == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    length = strlen(string);
    halflength = length / 2;

    for (i = 0; i < halflength; i++) 
    {
        if (string[i] != string[length - i - 1]) // comparing
            yesno = 0;
        break;
    }
    if (yesno) {
        cout << "You have successfully entered a palindrome." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You have not entered a palindrome." << endl;
        return main();
    }
}
}
```

I am unsure how to fix this, as a palindrome can not only be a sequence of letters, but a sequence of characters. If there is an easier way to compare the lines, then I would appreciate the help, as I have spent some time being frustrated at this.

Answer (score 0):

your program says,"You have successfully entered a palindrome." for mlaylam!

the problem is not having the break statement in the right place.

**the block should be enclosed within braces**, otherwise(as you've done), after checking the first character and last, the for loop will break thereby giving wrong result.

```
 if (string[i] != string[length - i - 1]){ // comparing
            yesno = 0;
            break;
        }
```